# Sort a TableView Column Item in JavaFX which is part of an HBox

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've a TableView which looks as shown in the linked image. [click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ugZ.png). Currently, I cannot sort the *Vertex ID* column but I can sort the *Community* column. Is there a way to sort table rows based on Vertex ID column? Please suggest. Below is the code for tableview and class *TableRow* which is the data model for tableView

Table View Code:

```
private TableView vertexTable;
List<TableRow> Data = new ArrayList<>();
Data.add(new TableRow(VertexID, color, communityID);
ObservableList<TableRow> obvData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Data);
vertexTable.setItems(obvData);
```

Data Model Code to be used in TableView

```
public class TableRow {

    public StringProperty Community = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public ObjectProperty Vertex = new SimpleObjectProperty();
    private int VertexID ;

    public CommunityTableViewRow(String pstrVertexID, Color pclrColor, String pstrCommunity) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10,5);
            rect.setFill(pclrColor);
            Group grpShape = new Group(rect);

            this.VertexID = Integer.parseInt(pstrVertexID);
            Text txtvertex = new Text(pstrVertexID);
            HBox hboxVertexID = new HBox(grpShape, txtvertex) ;
            hboxVertexID.setSpacing(5);
            hboxVertexID.setPadding(new Insets(2,2,2,2));
            hboxVertexID.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            this.Community = new SimpleStringProperty(pstrCommunity);
            this.Vertex = new SimpleObjectProperty(hboxVertexID);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the model with the rendering: these should be separate. In particular, you should have no UI elements in your model class.

The Vertex Id column appears to be defined by two pieces of data: an int id and a color. So I would start by creating a class to represent that. Note the color may actually have a more sensible "data" representation (e.g. it might be an enum representing a finite set of choices of something: I don't know what you are modeling here).

Since you want to be able to sort these values, you should make this class implement `Comparable<VertexID>`, and define the order to simply be the order defined by the integer.

```
public class VertexID implements Comparable<VertexID> {

    private final int id ;

    private final Color color ;

    public VertexID(int id, Color color) {
        this.id = id ;
        this.color = color ;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id ;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color ;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(VertexID other) {
        return Integer.compare(id, other.id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null) return false ;
        return (other instanceof VertexID) && ((VertexID)other).id == id ;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id ;
    }
}
```

Now your table data model should look like:

```
public class TableRow {

    private final StringProperty community = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final ObjectProperty<VertexID> vertexId = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public TableRow(int vertexId, Color color, String community) {
        setVertexId(new VertexID(vertexId, color));
        setCommunity(community);
    }

    public StringProperty communityProperty() {
        return community ;
    }

    public final String getCommunity() {
        return communityProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCommunity(String community) {
        communityProperty().set(community);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<VertexID> vertexIdProperty() {
        return vertexId ;
    }

    public final VertexID getVertexId() {
        return vertexIdProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setVertexId(VertexID vertexId) {
        vertexIdProperty().set(vertexId);
    }

    public final void setVertexId(int vertexId, Color color) {
        vertexIdProperty().set(new VertexID(vertexId, color));
    }
}
```

Now you set your table view up. Note that the display of the vertex id column is controlled by the `cellFactory` (**not** the `cellValueFactory`):

```
TableView<TableRow> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<TableRow, String> communityColumn = new TableColumn<>("Community");
communityColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().communityProperty());

TableColumn<TableRow, VertexID> vertexIdColumn = new TableColumn<>("Vertex IDs");
vertexIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().vertexIdProperty());

vertexIdColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<TableRow, VertexID>() {
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 5);
    private Group grpShape = new Group(rect);
    private Text textVertex = new Text();
    private HBox hbox = new HBox(5, grpShape, textVertex);

    {
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(2,2,2,2));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(VertexID vertex, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(vertex, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            textVertex.setText(Integer.toString(vertex.getId()));
            rect.setFill(vertex.getColor());
            setGraphic(hbox);
        }
    }
});
```

This provides the proper separation of the *data* (represented by the column's `cellValue`s) from the *presentation* of those data (represented by the column's `cell`s). The default sorting now works, because it sorts according to the data you provide (and the natural order of the data class for the column, `VertexID`, is defined to order by the integers).